# Inner ring on rotating wheel space station?

Tags: science-based, space-constructs

Could Space Station V, from 2001: A Space Odyssey have an inner ring?  Would the inner ring have a different G-force if the inner ring was halfway between the outer ring and the hub.  Would there be any limitations on this because of stresses on the structure.

Space Station V 
Diameter ~300 m (984 ft)
Height~150 m (495 ft) along rotational axis
Rotational Period 61 seconds
[information source](https://2001.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Station_V)

[image]

<sup>*Attribution: 2001.fandom.com 2019*</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, yes, and yes.

The station could have an inner ring.

If both rings have a rigid connection, the inner ring will experience a lower G-force than the outer ring. The acceleration is proportional to radius, so it will differ on various decks of the main ring as well.

Adding more structure adds stress, but probably no more than adding another deck to the outer ring would. The frames would have to be sized to support the loads.